# Can I get the following estimate for a family of solutions of SDE's?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Fix a time horizon $T>0$. Consider a fixed discretization parameter $\Delta>0$ and divide $[0,T]$ into intervals of the form $[K \Delta, (K+1)\Delta]$ for $K=0...\lfloor T/ \Delta \rfloor - 1$. Now consider a family of continuous stochastic processes on $[0,T]$, $\{Z^\epsilon\}_{\epsilon>0}$, depending on a small parameter $\epsilon>0$. In particular assume that $Z_t^\epsilon$ satisfies some SDE on $[0,T]$ with coefficients depending on $\epsilon$. Assume that $\{Z^\epsilon\}_{\epsilon>0}$ is continuous but its definition is different in each $[K \Delta, (K+1)\Delta)$

Now assume I can prove that that there exists $C>0$ (independent of $\epsilon, K$) such that
$$\mathbb{E}\left [\sup_{t \in [K \Delta, (K+1)\Delta ]} |Z_t^\epsilon| \right ]\leq C \epsilon $$

In this context I was wondering if I can prove that there exists $\bar C>0$ (independent of $\epsilon, K$) such that
$$\mathbb{E}\left [\sup_{t \in [0,T ]} |Z_t^\epsilon| \right ]\leq \bar C \epsilon $$
Of course we have
$$\mathbb{E}\left [\sup_{t \in [0,T ]} |Z_t^\epsilon| \right ]=\mathbb{E}\left [\max_{K=0...}\sup_{t \in [K \Delta, (K+1)\Delta ]} |Z_t^\epsilon| \right ] \geq \mathbb{E}\left [\sup_{t \in [K \Delta, (K+1)\Delta ]} |Z_t^\epsilon| \right ] $$
so we cannot immediately use our hypothesis but can I somehow get my thesis?

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding...  If the first bound $\mathbb{E}\left [\sup_{t \in [K \Delta, (K+1)\Delta ]} |Z_t^\epsilon| \right ]\leq C \epsilon$ works for any $\Delta > 0$ and any $K$ in range, what is stopping you from taking $\Delta = T, K =0$?

Comment: Hi, yes I confirm that I cannot choose $\Delta=T, K=0$. The discretization parameter is fixed at the beginning and I can only prove $\mathbb{E}\left [\sup_{t \in [K \Delta, (K+1)\Delta ]} |Z_t^\epsilon| \right ]\leq C \epsilon $ for each $K$. The reason is that actually $Z_t^\epsilon$ in my case is defined differently on each $[K \Delta, (K+1 )\Delta]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $M = \lfloor T / \Delta  \rfloor - 1$. Consider the following inequality:
$$\sup_{t \in [0,T]} |Z_t^\epsilon| = \max_{K = 0, \ldots , M} \sup_{t \in [K \Delta, (K+1)\Delta]} |Z_t^\epsilon| \leq \sum_{K=0}^M \sup_{t \in [K \Delta, (K+1)\Delta]} |Z_t^\epsilon|$$
which is, morally, simply $\|\cdot\|_\infty \leq \|\cdot\|_1$ in $\mathbb{R}^M$. Taking expectations,
$$\mathbb{E}\left( \sup_{t \in [0,T]} |Z_t^\epsilon| \right) \leq \sum_{K=0}^M \mathbb{E}\left( \sup_{t \in [K \Delta, (K+1)\Delta]} |Z_t^\epsilon| \right) \leq (M+1)C \epsilon$$
Which shows that setting $\bar{C}=(M+1)C$ suffices to get the desired bound.